# Xslt select condtions, how to generate a 2ndLevelNavigation?

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

I have a Content tree in Umbraco where I have 3 main pages with their subpages. I also have 5 other pages that are child of Homepage which they have 2 options set: umbIsChildOfHomePage = 1 and umbracoNaviHide = 1
Take a look at structure:
[image]

Now: I want to generate a umb2ndLevelNavigation for each page.

I have this in my xslt file

```
<xsl:variable name="items" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc and @level = 2]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']"/>
    <xsl:if test="count($items) &gt; 0">
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="$items">
                <li>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">last</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">first</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
```

which will work only for pages other than homepage.
So need to extra personalize xslt select. How do I do that?
This is what I tried. I appended it to the template because I dont't know how to append the condition in other select.

```
<xsl:variable name="itemsHomepage" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc and @level = 1]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) = '1' and string(umbIsChildOfHomePage) = 1]"/>
    <xsl:if test="count($itemsHomepage) &gt; 0">
        <ul>
            <!--<xsl:attribute name="class">
               a<xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/parent::*[@isDoc]/@id [string(umbIsChildOfHomePage) = 1 ]" />
            </xsl:attribute>-->
            <xsl:for-each select="$itemsHomepage">
                <li>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">last</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">first</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="name() = 'Link'">
                            <a href="{current()/linkUrl}" target="_blank">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
                            </a>

                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
                            </a>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!--<li>
                s:<xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/@id" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$RootNode/@nodeName"/>-<xsl:value-of select="$RootNode/@id"/>
            </li>-->
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
```

The issue is that even if I go to a page that does not have childs items of homepage will be shown even for a page that does not have childs.
How do I personalize the select to show only when a page that have those 2 parameters(showNavi, and isHomePageChild) set on true?
Thanks for your help.
Hope you understood the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial code is targeting the nodes from the top down to level '2' - which sounds correct for what you want, you just need to get it to render out

There's a [good example here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/10946-creating-multi-level-navigation-in-45-schema) of what you are trying to do.

Stripped that solution down ($level is set to 2) reminds me why I won't go near xslt again willingly!:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = current()/@id or $currentPage/../@id = current()/@id or $currentPage/../../@id = current()/@id">

...

<ul>
<!-- 1st navigation items -->
<xsl:for-each select="./child::* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node/@id = current()/@id"></xsl:if>
<li> .... </li>

<!--output 2nd level nevigation items -->
<xsl:if test="count(current()/child::* [@isDoc]) &gt; 0 and $currentPage/@id = current()/@id or $currentPage/../@id = current()/@id or $currentPage/../../@id = 
current()/@id">

<ul>
<!--output 3rd level nevigation items -->
<xsl:for-each select="./child::* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node/@id = current()/@id"></xsl:if>
<li> ... </li>
```

and so on...